# Excel Power Query: Adding a Column linked to a named range

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I am attempting to create a new column where each element is a number, but that number is a value that I have recorded in a named cell/range in my workbook.

I have a cell named SCALAR that has a value 1.18 and have tried the below but couldn't get it to work (I've even tried to change the column type).

```
#"Added Custom14" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom10", "Custom.1", each Excel.Workbook("SCALAR"){0}[Column1])
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AddColumn = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom10", "Custom.1", each Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="SCALAR"]}[Content]{0}[Column1])
```

Comment: Code only answers might solve the issue, but some explanation of how it solves the problem would help in learning to understand how to solve future problems.

Comment: Sure, im not the expert but essentially I fixed my own issue through syntax Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="SCALAR"]}[Content]{0}[Column1] instead of Excel.Workbook("SCALAR"){0}[Column1]